# Use meta/super/windows/whatever key to open KDE Plasma's application launcher (KDE Plasma + i3)

Tags: kde, i3, application, plasma, launcher

I have a setup with KDE Plasma and i3 that I've been absolutely loving, except for the fact that the windows key no longer works to open Plasma's application launcher like it does with Kwin. I did some research and found out that normally Plasma handles it by assigning Alt+F1 to the launcher and then using ksuperkey to allow a single windows key press to emulate that action. However, ksuperkey depends on Kwin to work - and that's been replaced by i3. I haven't found another way to do this.

Also, I mostly followed [this](https://github.com/avivace/dotfiles) when setting everything up.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the KDE launcher shortcut to Meta+F1 now opens the launcher with solely the Meta key :) 
PS I'm using Parrot OS.

Comment: It sounds to me like the OP is asking how to use a *single* key to open the launcher, while you're describing a two-key combination.

Comment: No I'm not Jeff. I'm describing the single key method.

Comment: This is why I employed the word solely.

Comment: This worked for me for a short time, but broke after a reboot. Un-assigning and re-assigning did not fix it.